# Kaleidoscope effect with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, crop

I want to crop an area from an input video, then rotate this area 90 degrees four times. The output video should look like this:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88221856/cropping.png]

**This is a before image:**
[image]

**This is an after image:**
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Make a kaleidoscope effect with `ffmpeg`

[image: kaleidoscope]

### Example command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -loop 1 -i mask.png -filter_complex \
"[1:v]alphaextract,split[a1][a2]; \
 [0:v][a1]alphamerge,transpose=1[e]; \
 [0:v][a2]alphamerge,transpose=2[w]; \
 [0:v]vflip,hflip[s]; \
 [0:v]pad=ih*2:ih*2:x=(ow-iw)/2[n]; \
 [n][s]overlay=W/2-w/2:W/2[bg]; \
 [bg][e]overlay=W/2:H/2-h/2[bg2]; \
 [bg2][w]overlay=0:H/2-h/2" \
-codec:a copy output.mkv
```

### FFmpeg filters used

- [`alphaextract`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#alphaextract) and [`alphamerge`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#alphamerge) for the alpha component
- [`split`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit) to make multiple copies of the alpha component
- [`transpose`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose)/[`vflip`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vflip)/[`hflip`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hflip) or whatever combination of similar filters you prefer
- [`pad`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) to make the background "canvas"
- [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) to place each video on the canvas

### Notes

- Use a recent `ffmpeg`. Either [download a Linux build of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) or follow a step-by-step [guide to compile `ffmpeg`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).
- You will need to make an image that contains an alpha mask. It needs to be the same frame size as your video input, so if `video.mkv` is 1920x1080, then `mask.png` also needs to be 1920x1080. You can [download the alpha mask](http://avmule.com/images/mask.png) from this example.
- `split` was used because filter graphs must have unique edges, meaning every label connects two "nodes" or filter. So you have to split the output of any filter if you want to send its output to two places.
- The black background color of the `pad` filter is visible in the corners. The `crop` filter can be used to remove it if you prefer.
- The audio is [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of being re-encoded.
- See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for additional information on controlling the output quality.