# FFMPEG filter to boxblur and greyscale a video using alpha mask

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Can someone show me how to enhance the example found here:
[FFmpeg - Apply blur over face](https://superuser.com/questions/901099/ffmpeg-apply-blur-over-face)

To do the following:

1. Use an input alpha mask PNG instead of a declared rectangular region
2. both blur *and* greyscale the masked region

This is another example - showing how to use an alpha mask file
[Crop triangular area with FFMPEG](https://superuser.com/questions/736388/crop-triangular-area-with-ffmpeg)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a method using [`alphamerge`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#alphamerge), [`hue`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hue), [`boxblur`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#boxblur), and [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay).

[image: original]
[image: blurred]
[image: mask]

<sub>Original input, filtered output, mask image.</sub>

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -loop 1 -i mask.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]alphamerge,hue=s=0,boxblur=5[fg]; \
 [0:v][fg]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output
```

- The mask should be the same size as the input. If it isn't you could use [`scale`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) or [`scale2ref`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) to resize it.
- The audio is [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) to avoid unnecessary encoding.